# how to fill (by code) datagridview (unbound) with allowUserToAddRows = false in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I'm using a dataGridView for display data (read from a MySQL). 
I don't want to have that last blank row wher users can write...

[image: This is how it looks just start debuging and after loading MySQL data:]

[image: This is what happens once I select an item]

I don't want at all to have that last blank row.
I already tried whit allowUserToAddRows = False, BUT, with this value for the property, I can not write (load) data from MySQL, by code.

Any different idea? Thansk

Comment: Post vb & sql code here

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and post (as text using the `{}` widget) a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You must be doing something wrong when loading your data. It will make no difference how `AllowUserToAddRows` is set, the data should load either way.